# How to combine multiple live(Video) streams in single stream? so that output will be multiple (splitted)videos in single video?

Tags: c#, directx, video-streaming

I am very new to the streaming.
My requirement is to combine multiple videos/streams in to single video.
So output will be single video showing multiple videos simultaneously in single player(Like security camera video).

Here is my sample code---

```
IGraphBuilder oFilterGraph = (IGraphBuilder)new FilterGraph();
VideoMixingRenderer9 oVideoMixingRenderer = new VideoMixingRenderer9();
oFilterGraph.AddFilter((IBaseFilter)oVideoMixingRenderer, "Video");

IVMRFilterConfig9 oVMRFilterConfig = (IVMRFilterConfig9)oVideoMixingRenderer;
oVMRFilterConfig.SetRenderingMode(VMR9Mode.Windowed);
oVMRFilterConfig.SetNumberOfStreams(2);
oVMRFilterConfig.SetRenderingPrefs(VMR9RenderPrefs.None);             

IVMRMixerControl9 oIVMRMixerControl = (IVMRMixerControl9)oVideoMixingRenderer;

NormalizedRect oNormalizedRect = new NormalizedRect();
oNormalizedRect.left = 0.0F;
oNormalizedRect.top = 0.0F;
oNormalizedRect.bottom = 0.5F;
oNormalizedRect.right = 0.5F;
NormalizedRect oNormalizedRect1 = new NormalizedRect();
oNormalizedRect.left = 0.5F;
oNormalizedRect.top = 0.5F;
oNormalizedRect.bottom = 1;
oNormalizedRect.right = 1;

int iStreamId1 = oFilterGraph.RenderFile("c:\\file1.wmv", string.Empty);
int iStreamId2 = oFilterGraph.RenderFile("c:\\file2.wmv", string.Empty);
oIVMRMixerControl.SetOutputRect(0, ref oNormalizedRect);
oIVMRMixerControl.SetOutputRect(1, ref oNormalizedRect1);          
oIVMRMixerControl.SetAlpha(0, 1);
oIVMRMixerControl.SetAlpha(1, 1);

IMediaControl oMediaControl = (IMediaControl)oFilterGraph;
oMediaControl.Run();
```

I tried with the code but could not succeed. It is showing only one video in control & not showing other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the VideoMixingRenderer in DirectShow.

This link provides an explanation of how to do it using C++:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/DirectShowVMR9.aspx

A .NET wrapper for DirectShow exists here:

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html

Comment: Could you please give some .net snippet for VideoMixingRenderer?
Where should I get the related information?